# use odata filter to compare two fields

Tags: odata

`{
 "name" : "Coffee",
 "quantity": 100,
 "restock": 10
}`

I want to use an odata $filter to show me ONLY items where the quantity is equal the restock number

Is it possible to do something like `$filter=quantity eq restock`I know that specific example fails. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible and you already have the syntax correct. You can just use `$filter=quantity eq restock`

I tried to find some data on the OData TripPin example service to illustrate this but couldn't find any properties that have the same value but hopefully these example illustrate that this is possible:

People where the `FirstName` property equals the `FirstName` property:
[http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinServiceRW/People?$filter=FirstName eq FirstName](http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinServiceRW/People?$filter=FirstName%20eq%20FirstName)

And people where the `FirstName` property does not equal the `FirstName` property:
[http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinServiceRW/People?$filter=FirstName ne FirstName](http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinServiceRW/People?$filter=FirstName%20ne%20FirstName)

Slightly less trivially, here is people where their user name contains a lowercase version of their first name:
http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinServiceRW/People?$filter=contains(UserName,tolower(FirstName))

Comment: I tried lowercase and uppercase but it is not worked

Comment: The lowercase and uppercase were just examples to show how you can compare two properties, it isn't specifically for your problem/system